# divide the comma separated string into columns with empty string

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a following string like this

```
str:=',1,,3,4,5,6,,8,9';
str2:=',a,l,,gj,,b';
```

How can I divide the comma and separated string into columns like this with using SQL only? (the ordering should be same as below)

```
COL
---------
NULL
1
NULL
3
4
5
6
NULL
8
9

COL2
----------
NULL
a
l
NULL
gj
NULL
b
```

Thanks

Comment: Just one row to be converted?

Comment: Is there a known maximum on the number of comma's?

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: I'm using oracle 12c

Comment: Comma separated values and SQL don't go very well together...

Comment: Many solutions in the [Splitting Delimited Strings documentation page](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/oracle/1968/splitting-delimited-strings#t=201702220918254961114).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cross apply` with hierarchical `connect by` to achieve this:

```
with t (text) as (select ',1,,3,4,5,6,,8,9' from dual union all
                  select ',1,,2' from dual)
select regexp_substr(text, '[^,]+', 1, lvl) x
from t cross apply (
    select level lvl
    from dual
    connect by level <= regexp_count(t.text, ',') + 1
    );
```

The above works for multiple rows at once.

If you have just one row to convert, use:

```
with t (text) as (select ',1,,3,4,5,6,,8,9' from dual)
select 
    regexp_substr(text, '[^,]+', 1, level) x
from t connect by level <= regexp_count(text, ',') + 1;
```

If you want to get the result in same order as it occured in the input string, try this:

```
with t (text) as (select ',1,,3,4,5,6,,8,9' from dual union all
                  select ',1,,2' from dual)
select replace(regexp_substr(text, '[^,]*,?', 1, lvl),',') x
from t cross apply (
    select level lvl
    from dual
    connect by level <= regexp_count(t.text, ',') + 1
    );
```

If your separator is `^|{`, make sure you escape the special chars properly. Try this:

```
with t (text) as (select '^|{1^|{^|{3^|{4^|{5^|{6^|{^|{8^|{9' from dual union all
                  select '^|{1^|{^|{2' from dual)
select replace(regexp_substr(text, '[^(\^\|\{)]*(\^\|\{)?', 1, lvl),'^|{') x
from t cross apply (
    select level lvl
    from dual
    connect by level <= regexp_count(t.text, '\^\|\{') + 1
    );
```

Comment: need by sequence, like following (NULL,1,NULL,3,4,5,6,NULL,8,9)

Comment: thanks for your ans, but how about if the separator is '^|{' instead of ',' using comma?

Comment: something like
1^|{3^|{'4^|{'^|{'^|{'5^|{'7^|{'8

Comment: thanks, really not good at regexp, long way to learn, anyway thanks!

Answer (score 0):

regex_replace + connect by does what you need,  BUT excluding NULL values, so a trick is needed in order to avoid null strings from the output of regex replace. In this case I add a # char to the input, before each ',' , then I remove it after regex_replace has done the job.

You can try with the following (this is of course the query for one column, you just need to replicate it for the 2nd)

```
select 
replace(result,'#','') from
(select
regexp_substr(replace(',SMITH,ALLEN,WARD,JONES',',','#,'),'[^,]+',1,level) result from dual
connect by regexp_substr(replace(',SMITH,ALLEN,WARD,JONES',',','#,'), '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another one using [`xmltable`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions228.htm):

```
SELECT DECODE (column_value, '-~-', NULL, COLUMN_VALUE)
FROM xmltable(('"' || REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(',1,,3,4,5,6,,8,9','^,|,$|,,', ',-~-,'),
              ',', '","') || '"'))
```

If you need a literal `NULL`:

```
SELECT TRIM(column_value)
FROM xmltable(('"' || REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(',1,,3,4,5,6,,8,9','^,|,$|,,', ',NULL,'),
              ',', '","') || '"'))
```

**Results**

```
NULL
1
NULL
3
4
5
6
NULL
8
9
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a recursive sub-query factoring clause (a.k.a. a Common Table Expression); here is an example that uses simple string functions and does not rely on (expensive) regular expressions:

**Sample Data**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id, list ) AS
SELECT 1, 'a,b,c,d' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Multiple items in the list
SELECT 2, 'e'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Single item in the list
SELECT 3, NULL      FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- NULL list
SELECT 4, 'f,,g'    FROM DUAL;          -- NULL item in the list
```

**Query**:

```
WITH bounds ( id, list, start_pos, end_pos, lvl ) AS (
  SELECT id, list, 1, INSTR( list, ',' ), 1 FROM table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         list,
         end_pos + 1,
         INSTR( list, ',', end_pos + 1 ),
         lvl + 1
  FROM   bounds
  WHERE  end_pos > 0
)
SELECT id,
       SUBSTR(
         list,
         start_pos,
         CASE end_pos
           WHEN 0
           THEN LENGTH( list ) + 1
           ELSE end_pos
         END - start_pos
       ) AS item,
      lvl
FROM   bounds
ORDER BY id, lvl;
```

**Output**:

```
        ID ITEM           LVL
---------- ------- ----------
         1 a                1 
         1 b                2 
         1 c                3 
         1 d                4 
         2 e                1 
         3 (NULL)           1 
         4 f                1 
         4 (NULL)           2 
         4 g                3
```

Answer (score -1):

use like bellow:

```
declare @ids varchar(max), @xml XML
                set @ids='135,136'
                SET @xml = cast(('<X>' + replace(@ids, ',', '</X><X>') + '</X>') as xml)


                SELECT xmlNode.value('.', 'varchar(50)')
                FROM @xml.nodes('X') as T(xmlNode)
```

Comment: Please indent the first row of code with 4 positions too, so it will be displayed as code

Comment: The question is for Oracle, so this syntax is not valid.